# How to do reshape operation on a single column in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a long pyspark dataframe as shown below:

```
+------+
|number|
+------+
|12.4  |
|13.4  |
|42.3  |
|33.4  |
|42.3  |
|32.4  |
|44.2  |
|12.3  |
|45.4  |
+------+
```

Ideally, I want this to be reshaped to an `nxn` matrix where `n` is `sqrt(length of pyspark dataframe)`.

While there is a solution by converting it into a numpy array and then reshaping it to `nxn` matrix but I want that to be done in pyspark. Because my data is super long (about 100 million rows).

So the expected output I am looking for is something along these lines:

```
+------+------+------+
|12.4  | 13.4 | 42.3 |
|33.4  | 42.3 | 32.4 |
|44.2  | 12.3 | 45.4 |
+------+------+------+
```

While I was able to do it properly by converting it to pandas then to numpy and then doing the reshape operation. But I want to do this transformation in Pyspark itself. Because the below code works fine for only a few thousand rows.

```
covarianceMatrix_pd = covarianceMatrix_df.toPandas()
nrows = np.sqrt(len(covarianceMatrix_pd))
covarianceMatrix_pd = covarianceMatrix_pd.to_numpy().reshape((int(nrows),int(nrows)))
covarianceMatrix_pd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is using `row_number` with pivot after we have a count of the dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
from math import sqrt
```

---

```
c = int(sqrt(df.count())) #this gives 3
rnum = F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1)))

out = (df.withColumn("Rnum",((rnum-1)/c).cast("Integer"))
 .withColumn("idx",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Rnum").orderBy("Rnum")))
.groupby("Rnum").pivot("idx").agg(F.first("number")))
```

---

```
out.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|Rnum|   1|   2|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   0|12.4|13.4|42.3|
|   1|33.4|42.3|32.4|
|   2|44.2|12.3|45.4|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I dont know for some reason it is successfully able to transform in the desired way. But the order is not correct. My data is double type with negative values as well. I crosschecked with a 4 row long df having values - [-0.002323, 0.002232, 0.003323, -0.0014]. the output I got from your snippet is along this -[ [0.002232,-0.0014],[-0.002323, 0.003323]]. Which is not along the expected results. Can you cross examine @anky ? I think it is because of negative values in the long dataframe.

Comment: I checked with your new code that you said. The order is still different. Additionally I crosschecked by just running this - > ```df.withColumn("Rnum",((rnum-1)/c).cast("Integer")).show()``` . the order changes by doing this operation as well ( given I have negative values in df)

Comment: @VishalAnand Order might change however is the Rnum assigned correctly? If yes then this should work. I tested your example in a community version and it worked

Comment: What if I had to get the output of the question in this order.  [[12.4, 33.4 , 44.2 ],
[13.4  ,42.3 , 12.3],
[42.3, 32.4, 45.4]]. What changes should be done in the code to acheive that @andy?

Comment: @VishalAnand try using Rnum like `df.withColumn("Rnum",(rnum-1)%c)`

Comment: i am using databricks with 64 cores cluster and using production data. The order is not preserved which makes the method useless. Is there any way this can be acheived in such a production level deployment? @anky